# How to replace modernizr.load?

Tags: javascript, modernizr

I'm trying to code a simple bubble shooting game. I follow a printed. For configuration the author says that "modernizr.load" component should be downloaded. As I found it's not in use any more. 
Can you suggest what should I use instead? Should I dowload the yepnope.js library somehow? I'm a newborn front-end developer and I learn all the time. I will appreciate every hint. Thanks.

Comment: Asking for such suggestions is not allowed on SO: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic"  http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thanks for comment. I have edited my question, so no recommendation is inserted. I used it only to paint the context, but maybe it's not needed.

Comment: You should be able to simply include the yepnope.js library before modernizr, and it will be used. See [the release notes](https://modernizr.com/news/modernizr-3-new-release-site), where it says *`Modernizr.load` has been deprecated in favor of using yepnope.js directly; from v3.0, yepnope.js must be included in the page in order for `Modernizr.load` to work: calling `.load()` will simply pass the arguments on to `yepnope();` this will be removed fully in a future release (#1241)*

Comment: Your question is still off topic as you are asking for software to use.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan: Thank you.

Comment: @Rob: Thanks. I will try to avoid it in the future.